# ngx-translate as service & map to an array

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-translate

I am trying to map an array passing it through the ngx-translate service. It must be late and I'm tired. This seems to be returning as undefined and for the life of me I cannot figure out why:

```
datasetLabels: any = ['DASHBOARD.PITCHING_VOLUME.SENT', 'DASHBOARD.PITCHING_VOLUME.RESPONDED', 'DASHBOARD.PITCHING_VOLUME.SECURED'];

this.datasetLabels = this.datasetLabels.map((label) => {
    this.translate.get(label).subscribe((res: string) => {
        console.log(res); // outputs correct translations
        return res;
    });
});
console.log(this.datasetLabels);
```

as you can see at the point I `console.log(res);` I am getting the correct values, but the function is not mapping back to the array?

Answer (score 0):

When you subscribe to an Observable, it means that you're working in an asynchronous way.

If you want to save the values outside the observable (which is not a really good idea, you should just keep them as a stream), you could do it like that:

```
const datasetLabels: string = [
  'DASHBOARD.PITCHING_VOLUME.SENT',
  'DASHBOARD.PITCHING_VOLUME.RESPONDED',
  'DASHBOARD.PITCHING_VOLUME.SECURED',
];

const getLabelsStreams: Observable<string>[] = labels =>
  labels.map(this.translate.get);

const labels$: Observable<string>[] = getLabelsStreams(datasetLabels);

forkJoin(labels$)
  .pipe(tap(labels => (this.datasetLabels = labels)))
  .subscribe();
```